# Change bootstrap column order inside PHP loop on mobile and tablet devices

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need help to change bootstrap column order inside php loop which counts two div`s (with class product). Each two divs (with class product) in loop contains two bootstrap columns (divs with class image and class description) with same order and then next two divs (with class product) has reverse order of bootstrap columns inside (divs with class description and class image).

The concept in php loop goes like this:

DIV_1 (Image + Description) DIV_2 (Image + Description)

DIV_3 (Description + Image) DIV_4 (Description)

and etc. in php loop

Everything works well on desktop but on mobile devices I would like to have normal layout on scroll where all div`s will have IMAGE first and then Description.

Full code:

```
<section class="products">
  <div class="container">

    <?php $sl=1; ?>
      <?php if(($sl==1)||($sl==2)) { ?>

        <div class="product col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="image col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <a href="#" class="moreLink">
                        <img src="" alt="" />
                    </a>
            </div>
            <div class="description col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="product-description left-triangle">
                    <h3><a href="#" class="moreLink">Product Title</a></h3>
                    <p>Description text goes here...</p>
                    <a href="#" class="moreLink btn dark ">Details</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
            $sl++; 
            }
        else 
            { ?>

        <div class="product col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="description col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="product-description right-triangle">
              <h3><a href="#" class="moreLink">Product Title</a></h3>
              <p>Description text goes here...</p>
              <a href="#" class="moreLink btn dark">Details</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="image col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
              <a href="#" class="moreLink">
                <img src="" alt="" />
              </a>
          </div>

        </div>

        <?php if($sl==3) 
            $sl++; 
        else 
            $sl=1; } ?>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: php doesn't know what resolution is your screen so you will need to use js

Comment: Yes php doesn't`t know screen resolution but probably js also is not good solution for this. It is just passing problem solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way - use css flexbox
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox make sense if I change flex-item classes for divs in loop with class product (class flex-container). If I use flex-item-a and flex-item-b for bootstrap columns (with class image and with class description).

**Is this solution mobile/tablet cross-browser ready?**

```
<section class="products">
  <div class="container">

    <?php $sl=1; ?>
      <?php if(($sl==1)||($sl==2)) { ?>

        <div class="product col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 flex-container">
            <div class="image col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 flex-item-a">
                    <a href="#" class="moreLink">
                        <img src="" alt="" />
                    </a>
            </div>
            <div class="description col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 flex-item-a">
                <div class="product-description left-triangle">
                    <h3><a href="#" class="moreLink">Product Title</a></h3>
                    <p>Description text goes here...</p>
                    <a href="#" class="moreLink btn dark ">Details</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
            $sl++; 
            }
        else 
            { ?>

        <div class="product col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 flex-container">
          <div class="description col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 flex-item-b">
            <div class="product-description right-triangle">
              <h3><a href="#" class="moreLink">Product Title</a></h3>
              <p>Description text goes here...</p>
              <a href="#" class="moreLink btn dark">Details</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="image col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 flex-item-b">
              <a href="#" class="moreLink">
                <img src="" alt="" />
              </a>
          </div>

        </div>

        <?php if($sl==3) 
            $sl++; 
        else 
            $sl=1; } ?>

  </div>
</section>
```

with css style:

```
.flex-container {
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width:100%;
}

.flex-item-a:nth-of-type(1), .flex-item-b:nth-of-type(2) { order: 1; }
.flex-item-a:nth-of-type(2), .flex-item-b:nth-of-type(1) { order: 2; }

.flex-item-a, .flex-item-b { width: 100%; height:auto; }
```